# Ant compile does not recognize plugin.jar library

Tags: java, ant

i am facing an issue in an ant build xml during compile process. My Ant command is pretty simple:

```
<target name="compile" description="Compilation target">                

    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="JARbuild">   
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation"/>   

    </javac>          
</target>
```

However i always get the following error

error: cannot find symbol

```
private final static JSObject jso = JSObject.getWindow(JMain.getInstance());
```

I am able to compile my project with netbeans ide, without running into an error, since the corresponding jar file (plugin.jar) is recognized as a library. I tried to add the library to classPath by setting sth. similar to:

```
<classpath>
            <path>
                <pathelement location="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\plugin.jar" />
            </path>
        </classpath>
```

However error still occurs. Somebody got a solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using escaped-backlashes, or unix-style seprators in your Windows path?

E.g.

```
<pathelement location="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\plugin.jar"
```

or

```
<pathelement location="C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/plugin.jar"
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but unfortunately does'nt have any impact.